# Angularjs ng-model doesn't work with input number type and arrow keys in Edge

Tags: html, angularjs, input, microsoft-edge

I have a input with `type="number"`, it is associated with a ng-model.I want to be able to press up and down arrows to update its value. However in Microsoft Edge the ng-model is not updated in this case, see my example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yZaGxkYG87C1YCNSKnf0?p=preview

Is there a way of updating the model, that's not using jquery? We want to avoid using jquery in controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's a bug from both angularjs and Edge, as seen in the discussion below:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15366

A snippet is proposed to fix the problem by oneself:

```
.directive('input', () => {
  if(currentBrowser!="edge") return {};

  return {
    link: (scope, elem) => {
      if (elem[0].type === 'number') {
        elem.on('keydown', evt => {
          switch (evt.which) {
            case 38:   // UP_ARROW
            case 40:   // DOWN_ARROW
              scope.$evalAsync(() => elem.triggerHandler('change'));
              break;

          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this. The problem is since you have not initialized in the controller there is an issue with display. It should work, but seemingly doesnt work in Edge. Everything else remains the same.

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{helloworld}}</h1>
    <input type="number" ng-model="md"/>
    <div ng-if="md">{{md}}</div>
  </body>
```

Check the code here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9Evcuj6AMP5DXqKZejg7

Comment: This code works for me in edge. No issues just declare the $scope.md in js controller in edge. It should work. Its because its undefined I guess. That should work. The above plunkr is made using edge so atleast iys working for me here. Are you getting any console errors in browser?

Comment: If thats still a problem then convert the input to string and do a js validation for a number and try

Comment: If you press arrow key up and down, do you see the number beneath the input box changing?